# How can i save this into a variable so that i can save it to a file

Tags: python

I have a bit of code which prints what I want to save but I cant save it as a variable because of the format. Please can you show me how to save this as a variable so that I can save it into a file

It wont let me add a picture but this is what I want to add to a variable (What its printing)

```
print(text[i],end="")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
x = text[i]
with open("output.txt", 'w') as f:
    f.write(x)
```

or

```
with open("output.txt", 'w') as f:
    f.write(text[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

Open a file:

```
f = open('filename','w')
```

Write a line of text to the file:

```
f.write(text[i])
```

And finally close the file:

```
f.close()
```